# Title and table not alligned when using lscape

Tags: tables, landscape

[image]I am using the lscape package to insert a landscape table, but the table I obtain is not alligned with its title (see image). In addition, I would like to place the table in the center of the page, and not at the bottom.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[tb]
\caption{Effect of Neighbors and Siblings}
\label{table_quality}
\resizebox{0.85\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}

TABLE CONTENT

\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item \emph{Notes:} 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The image doesn't seem produced with `lscape` as the page number is not rotated. Avoid `\resizebox` for tables.

Answer (score 1):

A `\centering` added in the `table` environment is enough. 
MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[tb]
\centering
\caption{Effect of Neighbors and Siblings}
\label{table_quality}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}}
\toprule 
B & \multicolumn{6}{c}{TABLE CONTENT\tnote{a}} \\
\midrule
A & Blah blah& Blah blah& Blah blah& Blah blah& Blah blah& Blah blah\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item a : A note
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```